# The resource cannot be found happens in MVC while controller exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an `area` named `fa` inside the `fa` i have some controllers ,as you can see one of them here:

```
  namespace UI.Areas.fa.Controllers
    {
        public class NewsController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /fa/News/

            private NewsRepository NewsRepository = new NewsRepository();
            private GroupRepository GroupRepository = new GroupRepository();
            public ActionResult Index(int? groupId, int? num)
            {
                ViewBag.slideshowNews = NewsRepository.FindBy(i => i.Group.LanguageType == "Persian" && i.Group.Type == "News" && i.ShowOnSlide == "Yes").OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).Take(6).ToList();
                ViewBag.slideshowNewsNav = NewsRepository.FindBy(i => i.Group.LanguageType == "Persian" && i.Group.Type == "News" && i.ShowOnSlide == "Yes").OrderBy(i => i.Id).Take(6).ToList();
                ViewBag.threetopnews = NewsRepository.FindBy(i => i.Group.LanguageType == "Persian" && i.Group.Type == "News").OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).Take(3).ToList();
                ViewBag.newsSubGroup = GroupRepository.FindBy(i => i.Type == "News" && i.GroupId != null && i.LanguageType == "Persian").OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).Take(6).ToList();
                ViewBag.morenewsSubGroup = GroupRepository.FindBy(i => i.Type == "News" && i.GroupId != null && i.LanguageType == "Persian").OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).Skip(6).ToList();
                int realnum = 1;
                if (num.HasValue) realnum = num.Value;
                if (groupId.HasValue)
                {
                    ViewBag.news =
                        NewsRepository.FindBy(i => i.Group.LanguageType == "Persian" && i.GroupId == groupId).Take(realnum * 8)
                                      .OrderByDescending(i => i.Id)
                                      .ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.news =
                       NewsRepository.FindBy(i => i.Group.LanguageType == "Persian" && i.Group.Type == "News").Take(realnum * 8)
                                     .OrderByDescending(i => i.Id)
                                     .ToList();
                }
                return View();
            }
            public ActionResult ShowDetails(int id, int group, int? num)
            {
                ViewBag.newsDetails = NewsRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == id).First();
                Group objGroup = GroupRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == group).First();
                ViewBag.Groups = GroupRepository.FindBy(i => i.GroupId == objGroup.GroupId && i.LanguageType == "Persian").OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).Take(6).ToList();
                ViewBag.moreGroup = GroupRepository.FindBy(i => i.GroupId == objGroup.GroupId && i.LanguageType == "Persian").OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).Skip(6).ToList();
                int realnum = 1;
                if (num.HasValue) realnum = num.Value;

                ViewBag.news =
                    NewsRepository.FindBy(i => i.Group.LanguageType == "Persian" && i.GroupId == group).Take(realnum * 8)
                                  .OrderByDescending(i => i.Id)
                                  .ToList();

                return View();
            }

        }
    }
```

But when i call this `url` `http://localhost:17442/fa/News`,this error happens

```
The resource cannot be found.
```

My global code :

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

Area registration :

```
public class faAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "fa";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "fa_default",
                "fa/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

The `routedebugger` result :[image]

Which parts should i check?

Comment: It is safe to assume that you have a call to `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` inside the `Application_Start` method of your `global.asax` ?

Comment: You also need a class that registers the area so that it gets picked up by the `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()`, normally a `faAreaRegistration` class is generated automatically if you use VS and add a new area. You have that in place as well?

Comment: if you add an action method `public ActionResult Test(){ return Content("inside test"); }` and you navigate to `http://localhost:17442/fa/News/Test` , do you get the "inside test" message or resource not found?

Comment: @cgijbels let me check it

Comment: @cgijbels i did that ,and same error happened

Comment: Ok, seems something is wrong with your route registrations then, now we can go back and forth and try to guess what the issue is, but I think it will be easier if you install the `RouteDebugger` NuGet package from `Phil Haack`, it is very lightweight and once you make your call at the above URL, you'll get a list of all registered routes at the bottom of your page, which should hopefully give you an idea why your route can't be found. If not, then don't hesitate to paste that list in your question, so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @cgijbels i update the question with the result

Comment: @cgijbels so could you please give me some help about the result ?

Comment: @EA try changing the namespace of the Controller from `UI.Areas.fa.Controllers` to `Exportvision.Areas.fa`. See if you still get the same error.

Comment: @danludwig it woooorkkkksssss,thank you what was the problem ?i need to changed it to UI ?how can i do that?

Comment: @EA now that is funny, because by looking at the output of the route debugger, the route is actually found, so it seems something else is triggering the 404?

Comment: @danludwig you have some inside information? As where does the `ExportVision` stuff come from as it is nowhere visible in the question?

Comment: @cgijbels it is visible in the question. Look at the rightmost "DataTokens" column in the route debugger screenshot. No inside information, I just read the question and viewed the route debugger screen shot image full screen. Though the route was matched, it could not be paired with a Controller because MVC was not looking for it in an expected namespace.

Comment: @danludwig yep, indeed, good catch! I focused to much on the fact that the route was actually found ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route debugger says it is looking for namespaces `ExportVision.Areas.fa.*`, however your controller is in the `UI.Areas.fa.*` namespace.

Either change the namespace of the Controller to `ExportVision.Areas.fa.Controllers` or explicitly include your custom namespace in the area route.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "fa_default",
        "fa/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "News", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "UI.Areas.fa.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding namespace to RegisterArea method:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "fa_default",
        "fa/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "UI.Areas.fa.Controllers" }
    );
}
```